# MySQL "TRIGGER AFTER" executes after return

Tags: mysql

Simple question but could not find an answer. That will help me understand strange wait locks timeout.

I'm using MySQL and PHP.

I have several triggers that run AFTER and INSERT statment.

Does MySQL returns the result to PHP **before** or **after** all the triggers are executed ?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply try it out. Put this in your trigger: `select sleep(10) into @asdf;` If your trigger takes at least 10 seconds, it's **after**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL return the result of the statement that invokes any triggers, after the completion of the triggers. As MySQL documentation on [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) says:

> An error during either a BEFORE or AFTER trigger results in failure of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.

The only way MySQL can notify the client that a statement failed as a result of an error in an `after` trigger is to send back the results **after** the trigger completed.